# What is the proper way of writing this statement

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to get a textbox value. In order to reach to the textbox i have written a series of children() function of JQuery which does not seem to be a proper way of achieving what i want here is my statement:

```
$("#" + lnkBtn.id).parents("#tabContainer_tabInqQuotes_POProcessingInqQuotes1_gvLineDetails_ctl00__0").children().children("table").children("tbody").children("tr").children("td").children("input")[0].value;
```

what is an alternative to this statement?

Comment: nop html textbox <input type="text"/>

Comment: add class and select that with class selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do everything in one selector:

```
var $parentElement = $("#textbox_parent");
var value = $parentElement.find("table input:first").val();
```

It would, of course, be simpler to just add a class (or id) to your `input` and select it like this:

```
var value = $("input.myInput").val()
```

But I realise that this is not always possible, especially since it looks like you're trying to select a certain textbox based on user action.

Answer (score 0):

It is a round-a-bout way to find your textboxes. Do you want ALL textboxes? if so, just $("INPUT"). Can you put a class on the textboxes you want? If so, you can use $(".textboxclass").